# startx script commandline to start VirtualBox VM on separate X server

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, x-windows

I am trying to start a VirtualBox VM on a separate X screen (in fullscreen) so I can switch between Linux and Windows XP by doing Ctrl + Alt + F<.

I am basically trying to do something like this:

```
startx "VBoxManage startvm XP" -- :4 
startx "VBoxManage startvm "XP"" -- :4 (is this correct for quotes within quotes??)
```

I get a "bad command line option "VBoxManage" back from the startx script so obviously I am not understanding the rules for how to write "shell magic".

How can I do this correctly, or perhaps there is a better way of achieving a VirtualBox VM on a separate X screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add something like this to your ~/.xinitrc file:

```
# ...
if [ "${DISPLAY}" = ":4" ]; then
  gnome-session &
  waitpid=$!
  vboxmanage startvm vmname
  wait ${waitpid}
fi
# ...
```

This would check if this is the display where you want to run your VM, then, start a gnome-session on background (or whatever session you want) and execute vboxmanage. The `wait ${waitpid}}` will keep everything running until you decide to either kill startx or exit from gnome.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not closing this (yet) because I would like to see if it is possible to solve this in other ways as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

For anybody else who stumbles upon this...

The best way to execute commands with startx is to place them in a shell script and then use: `startx ./example.sh :4`.

While this works with virtual box, vboxmanage doesn't continue running in the xsession once it has launched the virtual machine. Instead I have found `virtualbox --startvm "NAME" --fullscreen` actually keeps the xsession running.

Comment: `virtualbox --startvm "NAME" --fullscreen` is exactly what you need.